# Scroll a list of events to the first event of a given month

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of events(classes, lectures, etc.) stored in mysql.  I use php to list them out by date in a div on a web page.  I list out six months of events at a time and have a button for each of these months.  When one of these buttons is pressed I would like the list to scroll to the first event of that month. i.e. you press the June button and it will scroll to the first event in June. I am new to javascript and jQuery but I would have thought there would be able to find an example on the web but my searches came up empty.  I would appreciate any pointers or suggestions.  Thanks!!!

Comment: It is usually best to provide example code of what you are doing now - particularly how you are iterating over each item in MySQL, so that we can advise you more specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help if you were to provide example code. I am not familiar with PHP but what you are looking is largely HTML.

I assume that in PHP you have a loop (perhaps a `while`) which iterates over each item returned from MySQL, and then prints the event details.

Here is some pseudo-code

```
$monthOfLastEvent = null;
for each result received from mysql
    $monthOfThisEvent = ?; # You have to capture 'month' from the 'date', perhaps with substr
    if($monthOfThisEvent != $monthOfLastEvent) {
        print "<div id=\"month$monthOfThisEvent\"></div>"; # place a marker just before that event
        $monthOfLastEvent = $monthOfThisEvent;
    }

    ... # here is where you print the event details

}
```

Such code, when written in PHP language, will output HTML like

```
<div id="month1"></div>
event in month 1
event in month 1
<div id="month2"></div>
event in month 2
etc
```

The links to your months will be

```
<a href="#month1">Month 1</a>
<a href="#month2">Month 2</a>
etc.
```

These are called HTML bookmarks or **HTML anchors**. Essentially using `href="#x"` will bring you to an element with `id="x"` in your web page.

Comment: Thanks George Bailey. I hadn't considered putting each month is its own div.  This would give me an easy 'id' to point to. I do want to 'scroll' to the month and not just jump to it, but I think with an 'id' to point to I can find a way to make the scroll work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, a search for "smooth scroll to anchor" would probably find that answer. If not you could post a separate question. - Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Using the div to place a marker at the top of each month worked great.  Now I can hop from month to month.  Now to figure out the scrolling.  Thanks again for your help.